# Gradle: Copy submodule's output into other submodule resources

Tags: gradle

I have the next project structure.

```
\rootProj
    |
    +--\moduleA
    |      |
    |      +--\build
    |      |--build.gradle
    |      ...
    |    
    +--\moduleB
           |
           +--\main
           |     |
           |     +--\resources
           |     ...
           |
           |-build.gradle
           ...
```

I'm searching an approach to put everything from **moduleA\build** to **moduleB\main\resources**.
Could someone help me with this task?

I've googled about it but found nothing - I'm new in Gradle and it may be a cause I can't ask in the right way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts after reading your question:

- Usually you don't really want to copy the whole `build` folder, because it may contain intermediate files that are internal to the build process. Instead there's usually a task whose output is set to a `build/dist/` folder.
  *Note: `dist` can be anything, it's just an example here, for example for Java project it would be `build/libs/` produced by the `jar` task.*
- Cross-referencing files/tasks directly from a different module forbids some optimizations Gradle can do. Instead there are configurations and artifacts in Gradle that can expose and consume files. This also encapsulates *how* the artifacts are generated inside the module. All the consumers need to know is the name of the exposed configuration.
- It's not recommended to create overlapping output (i.e. write files to `src/main/resources/` directly), instead a separate folder that's added to the main resources source set is good practice.
- Based on the directory structure I assume you might be not using the Java plugin, I'll still keep the answer compatible with it, it should apply to other types of projects too.

So based on the above, here's a solution that is a bit more complicated, but it is adhering to the lazy configuration and project isolation practices used in Gradle nowadays. I'll also use Kotlin DSL as that's the recommended language now.

---

In `moduleA/build.gradle.kts` we expose the "output" of `moduleA`:

```kotlin
val distribution: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> by configurations.registering {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = false
}

artifacts {
    add(distribution.name, tasks.named("someTaskThatCreatesDist"))
}
```

Whenever this `distribution` configuration will be used by anyone, the `someTaskThatCreatesDist` task will execute to generate it.

---

In `moduleB/build.gradle.kts` we consume the artifact generated by `moduleA`:

```kotlin
val generatedOutput: Configuration by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = false
    isCanBeResolved = true
}

dependencies {
    // Repeat this with different projects names if you want to be aggregate stuff.
    generatedOutput(project(":moduleA")) {
        targetConfiguration = "distribution"
    }
}

val copyGeneratedOutput: TaskProvider<Copy> by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    from(generatedOutput)
    into(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("generatedOutput"))
}

sourceSets.main.configure { resources.srcDir(copyGeneratedOutput) }
```

Using `from(Configuration)` and `srcDir(TaskProvider)` ensures that the links are made and `:moduleA:someTaskThatCreatesDist` is executed before `:moduleB:processResources` is executed.

---

*Let me know if there are more info needed, I'll try to update the answer.*

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my question I've made the next solution:

```
buildscript{
    ext{
        generatedResOutDir = file("$buildDir/generated-resources")
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main{
        output.dir(generatedResOutDir, builtBy: 'copyRes')
    }
}

task copyRes(type: Copy){
    //for to be certain a directory 
    //we are going to copy from 
    dependsOn ':moduleA:build'
 
    from project(':moduleA').buildDir
    into '${generatedResOutDir}/static'
}
```

This solution is inspiried by [Gradle DSL SourceSetOutput doc.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html)